# Wordpress/ TinyMCE: prevent custom style from wrapping

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

In Wordpress I have created a custom style for the TynyMCE-editor so that the publisher of a page can add three columns in a text. I want the publisher to be able to select the text he wants to put in a column (in the visual editor) and then select the style "column 1/3" from the styles menu. The text is would be wrapped in a div with a column3-class that on the website creates a column that takes up 1/3 of the width of the page. The idea is that if you do that for 3 parts of texts, you'll get three columns next to each other.

Now, I got this to work (for the most part), but the editor behaves oddly when I try to apply the styles.

I defined the style with the following

```
array(
'title' => 'column 1/3',
'block' => 'div',
'classes' => 'column3',
'exact' => true,
'wrapper' => true
)
```

The html I try to put into columns is as followed:

```
<h2>Column 1</h2>
<p>Text of column one</p>

<h2>Column 2</h2>
<p>Text of column two</p>

<h2>Column 3</h2>
<p>Text of column three</p>
```

Now, in the visual editor, if I select the first h2 and p and then choose "column 1/3" from the styles menu, the code gets like this:

```
<div class="column3">
<h2>Column 1</h2>
<p>Text of column one</p>
</div>
```

which is the way I want it. Now if I select the second h2 and p, wanting it to be the second column, the code gets like this:

```
<div class="column3">
<h2>Column 1</h2>
<p>Text of column one</p>
<h2>Column 2</h2>
<p>Text of column two</p>
</div>
```

The second h2 en p get into the same div, but I want them to be in a seperate div like this:

```
<div class="column3">
<h2>Column 1</h2>
<p>Text of column one</p>
</div>
<div class="column3">
<h2>Column 2</h2>
<p>Text of column two</p>
</div>
```

I can avoid this behaviour by adding two enters between the /p and the h2, but then a non-breaking space appears between the columns causing them not to align properly. I know I can remove the non-breaking space via the text-editor, but I rather not let the publishers of the website wade through the html-code directly.

How can put the style only on the text I select and let TinyMCE ignore the blocks surrounding it?
And if that's not possible, can I remove/filter the non-breaking space between the divs in the editor (not in the template, I know how to do that, but I rather not filter the content there)?

*added march 4:*

Though I still haven't found a solution, I've found a way to work around it.
I have added the styles for the column3 class to the editor-style.css. So an publisher can type the content for column one add two enters, then column three, two enters, etc.

Then he can select the text for column one and apply the style, then for column two and three. Now he visually sees the enters as he sees the misalignment of the columns. Now he can select the enters above the column and remove them. A bit more work, but an acceptable workaround.

Still curious for an answer on my first question: How can put the style only on the text I select and let TinyMCE ignore the blocks surrounding it?

Comment: Does this happen live, or the div get collapsed after saving only?

Comment: That happens live. The css in editor-styles.css is applied on the content in the editor, so you directly see what you are doing.